# How to find the third latest date from a list of dates

Tags: python, list, datetime

There is a list of dates in the form of array list
Example : 
11/02/2012
21/04/2019
12/03/2061
11/09/1961
22/08/2014

We will have to return the third latest date from the above list

I feel we will have to first sort in descending order of year and take the third latest date from that

Could you please give me a suggestions on this?

Comment: how did you get that array?

Comment: You are expected to attempt to solve the problem yourself before asking a question here. You already have a plan for a solution that might work, now you can just try to implement that.

Comment: You have a list of what, exactly? `datetime` objects? Strings?

Comment: You literally have to Google these three majestic words `"python datetime sort"` and let Google wind take you to learning land.

Comment: That array was the example declared by my own

Comment: The list contains date objects

Comment: @moulirv: Did anyone of the answers worked for you?

Answer (score 3):

Is this the way you expect

```
>>> import datetime
>>> list = ['11/02/2012', '21/04/2019', '12/03/2061', '11/09/1961', '22/08/2014']
>>> d_list = [ datetime.datetime.strptime(d,'%d/%m/%Y') for d in list]
>>> d_list
[datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 11, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 21, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2061, 3, 12, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1961, 9, 11, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 22, 0, 0)]
>>> sorted(d_list)
[datetime.datetime(1961, 9, 11, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 11, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 22, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 21, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2061, 3, 12, 0, 0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have datetime object in a list:

```
l = [list containing datetime objects]
l.sort()
l[2]
```

Should give you third latest date

Answer (score 0):

**Without** using the built in libraries, one way to do this is to:

1. Get the year, month, and date into a tuple. For instance, `"11/02/2012"` can be represented as `(2012, 02, 11)`.
2. Run sort.
3. Retrieve the third latest date on the sorted list using `sorted_dates[-3]`.

We can get the year, month, and date in the following way:

```
(d, m, y) = "11/02/2012".split('/')
```

Then, simply reverse the tuple, and run sort.

Comment: Assuming there isn't a year 2016 and a year 17. Datetimes are tricky.

Comment: This is not what OP has asked for.

Comment: @Rahul Why not? I didn't give him the entire answer. Just a few hints.

Comment: OP wants third latest date from list of dates.

Comment: @Rahul That's just a simple `sorted_dates[-3]` from the list of sorted dates. This answer was more about how to sort the dates.

Comment: Which is the reason not to use already available built-in libraries? It goes against one of the main good practices of programming: don't reinvent the wheel. Unless it is for educational purposes (and the OP doesnt seem to care about it).

Comment: @ImanolLuengo I assumed it was for educational purposes.

Answer (score 0):

So before working on dates you actually have to convert it into actual datetime object so simply do this:

```
from datetime import datetime


lst = ['11/02/2012' ,'21/04/2019' , '12/03/2061' , '11/09/1961' , '22/08/2014']
lstnew = []
for x in lst:
    lstnew.append(datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y'))
```

now you can run the sort or find the max

for sorting the list use `sorted(lstnew)` for max use `max(lstnew)`